# How to log time stamp in Makefile before every line executes under target

Tags: makefile

My make file target has several steps. Example below

```
do-something:
    cat Dockerfile
    ls
```

I want to display time stamp before invoking a command. I could like below. Is there a better and concise way?

```
do-something:
    echo $(shell date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N') calling step1
    cat Dockerfile
    echo $(shell date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N') calling step2
    ls
    echo $(shell date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N') Done
```

Answer:

I could build my solution using the answers below.

```
logLine = @date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N $1'

do-something:
    $(call logLine, calling step1)
    cat Dockerfile
    @date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N calling step2'
    ls
    $(call logLine, Done)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you use the `shell` make function to call `date` but not to call `cat` or `ls`? What essential difference do you make between these 3 commands that motivates this?

Comment: `cat` and `ls` are not the actual steps under target. They are only used as an example. Does that help?

Comment: No, not really, I still don't understand why, while you apparently know that make recipes are already shell scripts (else you would not call `cat` or `ls` in a recipe), you decide to use `$(shell ...)` to call another command. I guess that, on the command line, you would not call `date` differently than `cat` or `ls`, would you? And as it is quite common I'd really like to understand, there is maybe something here that deserves attention and that could help improving our answers about `make`.

Comment: Right, I am calling shell commands under  make target. My aim is to add some message prefixed with time stamp before calling shell command. Is there a way to avoid repetitive `$(shell date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N')` in my `echo` lines

Comment: First, you could simply use `date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N calling step1'` instead of the less concise `echo $(shell date ...)`. Why you used `$(shell ...)` was my main question. Second, if you are asking if make has an option or other feature that can automate this then no, there is no make option that does this for you. But you can simplify a bit using make macros, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$(shell ...)` in make recipes is almost always wrong because make recipes are already shell scripts and because of the time at which `$(shell ...)` is expanded by make.

Instead you could simply use:

```
do-something:
    date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N calling step1'
    cat Dockerfile
    date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N calling step2'
    ls
    date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N Done'
```

And to simplify a bit you could define a macro:

```
date = date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N $1'

do-something:
    $(call date,calling step1)
    cat Dockerfile
    $(call date,calling step2)
    ls
    $(call date,Done)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I can add `@date` to avoid printing of command on the terminal.

```
logLine = @date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N $1'

do-something:
 $(call logLine, calling step1)
 sleep 3
 @date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N calling step2'
 sleep 4
 $(call logLine, Done)
```

Comment: Note that you can add the `sleep` command to your macro: `logLine = @date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N $1'$(if $2,; sleep $2)'`. And then: `$(call logLine,calling step1,3)` or `$(call logLine,Done)`.

Comment: That is misunderstood. I should have stick to original `ls` and 'cat'. I was using `sleep` for testing to check if answer really works :)

Comment: As you can call the macro with or without the second argument you can keep it and use it or not. This will allow to continue testing as long as needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better and concise way?

Yes, you don't need (and really shouldn't) call the shell when parsing the makefile (which is what $(shell ...) does):

```
do-something:
    date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N'
    cat Dockerfile
    date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N'
    ls
    date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N'
```

Moreover you can have the date command in a variable:

```
ECHO_TIMESTAMP := date -u +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%N'

do-something:
    $(ECHO_TIMESTAMP)
    cat Dockerfile
    $(ECHO_TIMESTAMP)
    ls
    $(ECHO_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Sorry, i have to edit my question! Your answer helps.